# Can`t upload files in course Canvas LMS

Tags: nginx, canvas, file-upload, ubuntu-18.04, canvas-lms

When i go to course in Canvas LMS. And click Files -> Choose file to upload

But i ca`nt upload file. And website response Error: Request failed with status code 500

My Server: Ubuntu + Nginx

Thanks

[Click here show my Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThEHX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Are you still suffer from the problem?

Have you checked your size limitation?
You might suffer from upload size restrictions.

Comment: Hi bro ! Now we can`t upload file. i edited nginx.conf file

Comment: You edited your nginx.conf file then now you cannot upload
or you cannot upload so you edited you nginx.conf?